# Creating histogram from random numbers

Tags: java

When i try to create a histogram from the random data taken from a file my program adds the numbers between the range instead of increasing the star number. suppose i have 3 numbers (2,3,7) in a  range of 1-10. instead of printing 3 stars, its printing the sum of 2,3 and 7. what is the problem here? please help!
thank you.

```
import javax.imageio.IIOException;
import java.util.*;     // import all the Input/Ouput classes
import java.io.*;       // import all the Utility classes (Scanner, etc.)


public class histogram
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
            throws IIOException, FileNotFoundException

    {

        int word, i, j, h1 = 0, h2 = 0, h3 = 0, h4 = 0, h5 = 0,
                  h6 = 0, h7 = 0, h8 = 0, h9 = 0, h10 = 0,     // integer variable for loop iteration
             sum = 0, // sum of all the letters
             avg_ch = 0, // average of all the letters in a word
             asci ; // ascii value of the chracters
             
        char ch = 0;
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);     // attach to System.in to for console input
        System.out.printf("Please enter the input file name: ");     // Display message
        String inputfilename = scan.next();    // prompts user for input file name to read.
        System.out.printf("Please enter the output file name: ");     // Displays message
        String outputfilename = scan.next();    // prompts user for output file name.

        //  makes the input and output file names constant.
        final String FILENAME_DATA = inputfilename;
        final String FILENAME_REPORT = outputfilename;

        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File(FILENAME_DATA));    // opens input file
        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter( new File(FILENAME_REPORT));    // opens output file.

        while (scanFile.hasNext() == true)     // repeat until there is no items left.
        {

            word = scanFile.nextInt();    // scans the item names from input file 
            
                 if (word >0 && word <11)
                 {
                      h1++;
                 }
                 
                 else if (word >10 && word <21)
                 {
                      h2++;
                 }
            

                 else if (word >20 && word <31)
                 {
                      h3++;
                 }
                
                 else if (word >30 && word <41)
                 {
                      h4++;
                 }
            

                 else if (word >40 && word <51)
                 {
                      h5++;
                 }
                
                 else if (word >50 && word <61)
                 {
                      h6++;
                 }
            

                 else if (word >60 && word <71)
                 {
                      h7++;
                 }
                
                 else if (word >70 && word <81)
                 {
                      h8++;
                 }
            

                 else if (word >80 && word <91)
                 {
                      h9++;
                 }
                
                 else if (word >90 && word <100)
                 {
                      h10++;
                 }
            
            
        }
        for (i=0; i< h1 ; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("*");    // Display message
                outfile.printf("*");    // prints message to the output file
                 
            }
            System.out.println();
                
            for (i=0; i< h2 ; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("*");    // Display message
                outfile.printf("*");    // prints message to the output file
                 
            }
            System.out.println();
            
            for (i=0; i< h3 ; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("*");    // Display message
                outfile.printf("*");    // prints message to the output file
                 
            }
            System.out.println();
            
            for (i=0; i< h4 ; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("*");    // Display message
                outfile.printf("*");    // prints message to the output file
                 
            }
            System.out.println();
            
            for (i=0; i< h5 ; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("*");    // Display message
                outfile.printf("*");    // prints message to the output file
                 
            }
            System.out.println();
            
            for (i=0;  i< h6 ; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("*");    // Display message
                outfile.printf("*");    // prints message to the output file
                 
            }
            System.out.println();
            
            for (i=0;  i< h7 ; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("*");    // Display message
                outfile.printf("*");    // prints message to the output file
                 
            }
            System.out.println();
        
            for (i=0 ; i< h8 ; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("*");    // Display message
                outfile.printf("*");    // prints message to the output file
                 
            }
            System.out.println();    
            for (i=0 ; i< h9 ; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("*");    // Display message
                outfile.printf("*");    // prints message to the output file
                 
            }
            System.out.println();
            
            for (i=0; i< h10 ; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("*");    // Display message
                outfile.printf("*");    // prints message to the output file
                 
            }
            System.out.println();
        
        outfile.close();    // closes th eoutput file
        scanFile.close();   // closes the input file
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your input data, your result and expected result. I tested your code on some numbers, only removed this file I/O stuff and I got a rather decent histogram. No problem with printing algorithm to me, I/O on the other hand...

Comment: **input data**

6 75 90 83 45 4 22 53 56 7 73 15 41 60 74 96 38 3 55 69 5 61 19 48 29 95 59 2 30 76 9 62 34 20 72 99 98 12 42 27 23 65 46 89 52 10 85 32 88 28 82 84 97 47 67 21 16 43 44 39 57 14 31 24 25 94 11 87 33 92 35 91 13 40 18 17 66 8 77 36 78 51 1 80 79 81 93 64 54 70 100 68 50 63 86 26 49 71 37 58

**output data**

> run histogram
Please enter the input file name:  [DrJava Input Box]
Please enter the output file name:  [DrJava Input Box]
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
*********

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you are printing a newline to System.out between histogram bars, but not to the output file. This would produce an output file with all bars stacked on one line.

**Other random tips:**

You could simplify your if-else stack:

```
if (word <= 0)
{
    // do not increment any counters
}

else if (word < 11) // can't be less than or equal to 0 because that was already handled above
{
    h1++;
}

else if (word < 21) // can't be less than 11 because that was already handled above
{
    h2++;
}

else if (word < 31) // can't be less than 21 because that was already handled above
{
    h3++;
}
            
... etc
```

Also, it's standard for java classes to start with a capital letter.

Comment: i am just testing the program right now. will fix the output file after the program runs correctly. which currently isnt sadly